# SQL count total of values in column where other column value occurs multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables as example (columns D and F are irrelevant to this and just for showing there are more columns in the real table):

```
| A | B | C |
|123| 1 | 3 |
|456| 2 | 1 |
|123| 3 | 2 |
```

and

```
| a | D | E | F    |
|123| & |Ana|apple |
|456| * |Eva|pear  |
|789| % |Ola|orange|
```

"A" and "a" symbolize values linking the tables.

I'd like to on my page display a table that adds the total of values in column C where the rows in A have several of same value.

This means that the example above for row A = 123, which occurs in that column twice, would be a total of 5 displayed in a single row (values from column C in both rows summed up to 5. 2 + 3 = 5). For A = 456 the total would equal 1 as 456 occurs only once in column A and at that occurance has the value 1 in column C, as above displays.

The end result desired is a table like:

```
| a | E | D | c |
|123|Ana| & | 5 |
|456|Eva| * | 1 |
```

Where "c" symbolizes the total I want.

Is there a good way to do this in an SQL query which allows for simple output with help of PHP for my page?

Comment: [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) + [aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) functions. So, yes, it's possible. Writing it is your job. We (maybe) help fix what you've written, not write it for you.

Comment: `A = 123, which occurs in that column twice, would be a total of 5 ` why 5? And what is your expected result with that data.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza If you look at column A where 123 occurs twice, in column C it has the values 2 and 3. 2 + 3 = 5.

Comment: OK, but still you havent show us what is your desire output with that data. `|a | E | D | c |`  are just column header. We need to know what is the result you want

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza Example values from text added to example result table.

Comment: Your result table looks incomplete doesnt have `456`, and what value you want for `D` empty/null/random?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza As mentioned in the question the values for empty fields are irrelevant to this matter and they were excluded to avoid confusion.

Comment: well they are relevant if you include it on your ouput because affect how you write the query.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza Not in this case, the values of D won't matter, the column should just be there. I've added dummy values, but again, they won't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly what you are looking for, you likely want to use some SQL functions that help in such cases.

```
select a, E, D, sum(C) as c 
from t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.A = t2.a 
group by a, E, D
```

`sum()` will sum up the values of C for each unique occurence of a, E and D

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza May I ask what about Behrang's example makes the join non-explicit? (I've not been learning SQL for very long, I'm curious).

Comment: @Zarkaylia Check the edited  history, He already fix the code.

Comment: I use SQL since 20 years. Back in the days it was cool to connect your tables as part of the where clause :)

Comment: @BehrangDadsetan Oh, I see, thank you very much for explaining. (Excuse delayed answers on if this works, I'm trying to read up on and understand it properly before implementing it.)

Comment: @BehrangDadsetan Is ok, but we always can learn new things. Specially when help us improve read our code. That sintaxis has been deprecated since SQL Server 2008,

Comment: btw @Zarkaylia I think this is the solution you want.

Comment: @BehrangDadsetan I have now tested your solution and it works very well. Thank you again for all the help.

Comment: Glad it could help. Also glad it worked as it was quite theoritical. Thanks again Juan Carlos for pointing out the explicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

you should write something like

```
select A, sum(C) from first_table group by A
```

If you would combine it with values of the second table, you should use join

Answer (score 0):

i got it

**select a,sum(c) from demo2 where a = a group by a;**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyEqU.png